# Why is X the longitude and Y latitude for com.datastax.driver.dse.geometry.Point?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

The constructor for `com.datastax.driver.dse.geometry.Point` is `Point(double x, double y)`

The documentation says

> the X coordinate is the longitude and the Y is the latitude.

Why is the X the longitude and Y the latitude? Seems counter intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just guessing here, but it feels intuitive to me. In mathematics, the Y-axis is usually the vertical one and X-axis is the horizontal one. Latitude lines intersect the Y-axis, so they have a Y-value and they are parallel with the X axis.

```
All points on equator have coordinate (x=alpha, y=0) for alpha in [-180, 180]

y
^
|
|
|- - - - - - - - - - - - (equator)
|
|
+--------------------> x
```

Comment: Doh it's clear when you put it that way. My mind was stuck to the thought Longitude is vertical so it's Y and Latitude is horizontal so it's X.

Comment: Glad it helped!